# How to apply a function on groupby-ed groups?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to apply a function to groupby groups. Could not make it work.
Here is my data:

```
ID      DATE        ABROAD
1      2019-1-2        1
2      2019-1-2        0
1      2019-1-4        1
1      2019-1-7        1
2      2019-1-7        1
1      2019-1-8        0
1      2019-1-19       1
2      2019-1-11       1
```

What I want is

```
ID    #ofTravels
1      2
2      1
```

I want to find how many times a person has traveled. So here is my function

```
def no_travels(x):
    x.sort_values('DATE', ascending=True, inplace=True)
    current_state = x.iloc[0].ABROAD
    num_travels = 0
    for state in x['ABROAD']:
         if state != current_state:
              num_travels+=1
              current_state = state
    return num_travels
```

As I understood x is a group that is groupbyed. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is `groupby` with `diff`, we get the different for each `ID`, if the `diff` of `ID` equal to `0` which belong to one tripe it will return `False` , if not return `True` , then we just need `sum` up to find how many `True` we have

```
df.groupby('ID')['ABROAD'].apply(lambda x : x.diff().ne(0).sum()-1)
Out[1182]: 
ID
1    2
2    1
Name: ABROAD, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I want to order by time and successice ABROAD value 1 as 1 travel. Tried yours but it was not what I wanted. Thanks